# No response from Javascript SDK find call

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm working with the cloud code javascript SDK. I'm trying to run a query, but it seems that the "find" method never receives a response. Here's what I've got so far:

```
    var query = new Parse.Query("Report");

    var sixteen_h = new Date();

    sixteen_h.setHours(sixteen_h.getHours() - 16);

    query.greaterThan("createdAt", sixteen_h);
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        console.log("Got pain results!");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
```

Neither of these console logs are ever executed! Any ideas here? I've tried it both with and without the "query.greaterThan()" part and get no response both times. I've tried putting various log statements throughout it but can't see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this in a beforeSave function. Apparently you can't do that. Once I moved this to an afterSave function then it worked fine!